# Java - Selenium webdriver to access <a> within <li> element of a <ul>

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul class=someclass id=someuniqueid">
  <li>
    <a>Some Text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>SomeText</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>SomeText</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>SomeText</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>SomeText</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a>SomeText</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I want to loop through the li elements and then click on the  tags of all the elements.

I am using following code to do that

```
@FindBy(xpath="xpath of li elements within ul")
    List<WebElement> listLinks;

public void listLoop() {
        for (int i = 0; i < listLinks.size() ; i++)
        {
            listLinks.get(i).click();           
            System.out.println(listLinks.get(i).getText());
        }
```

When I am running the test, it displays the text of all li elements but it onlu clicks on specific links, not all of them.

Can someone help with how to click on a tag within li element within a ul element

Comment: I would suggest adding a little bit of time delay between each loop entry.

Comment: Basically what I am looking for is a way to use a for loop to click <a> in the above HTML part.

Answer (score 0):

first of all try adding a hard wait between each click just to make sure anything happening on background not causing the issue.

if that works well you can use Explicit wait to wait until any new window/tab gets opened after clicking on a tag

Comment: Basically what I am looking for is a way to use a for loop to click <a> in the above HTML part.